# Facebook Connect not working in IE8

Tags: facebook, authentication, internet-explorer-8

I have 2 applications set up on facebook. One for development/testing and one for production. With Firefox I can connect to both of them but with IE8 I can connect only to the development app. When I try to connect to the production app, after entering the credentials, I get the following error message:

> An error occurred with MyApp. Please try again later.

The site URL of my development app is `http://localhost:8080/test/` and the domain is blank.
The site URL of my production app is http://www.myapp.com. and the domain is myapp.com

The FB.init method looks like this:

```
FB.init({
    appId: '${fbApplicationId}',
    status: true,
    cookie: true,
    xfbml: true,
    channelUrl: 'http://myapp.com/xd_receiver.jsp'
});
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check the Side Domain and Site URL on Facebook. This error usually means your site URL is different from the one you are on while trying to connect.

Try to change the URL of the xd_receiver, add "www.", to http://www.myapp.com/xd_receiver.jsp

Comment: You're right, the xd_receiver URL was not created correctly. Fixed it, thanks.